# Factory method with dependent type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

I am struggling with dependent types in Scala 2.11.7. Here is the context:

```
trait Counter {
  type T
  def zero: T
  def incr( t: T ): T
}
object IntCounter extends Counter {
  type T = Int
  val zero = 0
  def incr( t: Int ) = t + 1
}

case class Foo( counter: Counter )

def twice( foo: Foo )( cntr: foo.counter.T ): foo.counter.T =
  foo.counter.incr( foo.counter.incr( cntr ) )
```

So far so good, everything compiles. However I would like to add an object which contains both a `Foo` instance and a corresponding counter state. For instance:

```
trait Bar {
  val foo: Foo
  val current: foo.counter.T
}
```

The definition is OK (provided I use abstract vals). But I cannot define a factory method (aka smart constructors). All my naive attempts fail to compile. For example, the definition:

```
def bar( f: Foo )( cntr: f.counter.T ): Bar = new Bar {
  val foo = f
  val current = cntr
}
```

fails to compile with the error:

```
xxx: overriding value current in trait Bar of type this.foo.counter.T;
value current has incompatible type
   val current = cntr
       ^
```

How can I force the compiler to understand that both type are indeed the same ? I could solve the problem with generics instead but I prefer to avoid this option if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `bar` is single constructor for `Bar`, you could solve it like this:

```
sealed trait Foo { //can't be case class because you can't even call `twice` method then
  type Ctr <: Counter
  type Z <: Ctr#T
  val counter: Ctr
}

def foo[Ct <: Counter](ctr: Ct): Foo{type Ctr = Ct} = new Foo {
  type Ctr = Ct
  type Z = ctr.T
  val counter = ctr
}


sealed trait Bar {
  type Ctrr <: Counter
  type TT <: Counter#T
  val foo: Foo {type Ctr = Ctrr}
  val current: TT
}

def bar[Ct <: Counter]( f: Foo{type Ctr = Ct} )( cntr: f.counter.T )(implicit ev: Ct =:= f.Ctr): Bar {type Ctrr = Ct; type TT = f.counter.T} = new Bar {
  type Ctrr = Ct
  type TT = f.counter.T 
  val foo = f
  val current = cntr
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val br = bar(foo(IntCounter))(5)
br: Bar{type Ctrr = IntCounter.type; type TT = Int} = $anon$1@35267fd4

scala> br.foo.counter.incr(br.current)
res41: Int = 6
```

The disadvantage here is that you have to specify (and maintain) the same root-type between `TT` and `foo` members wherever you create a new `Foo` instance.

Comment: I like your solution, but as you mentioned, it does not express the fact that `TT`must be the same time as `foo.counter.T`. As a last resort I could seal the trait `Bar`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. For example `bar( Foo( IntCounter ) )( 0 )` produces a compile error.

Comment: @paradigmatic that's the issue with case classes wrapper itself: `val c = Foo(IntCounter).counter; val num: c.T = 5; error: type mismatch` probably, you can't even call your `twice` function

Comment: Thanks I start seeing the real issue, do you have an idea for a replacement for the case class wrapper ? I need this double level of indirection because I must pack related data in `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks you for your update. However, it's still not usable for me, because the compiler does not unify the types: `res2.foo.counter.incr( res2.current )` does not compile with a type mismatch error. The compiler is still not able to unify the types.

Comment: @paradigmatic that's because it sees every counter as a `Counter`, so we need to generalize it `Ct <: Counter` and add several explicit type annotations (for stupid scala-compiler) - see my new update